# Linear programming transportation optimization with procedence restrictions

Tags: r, restriction, linear-programming, glpk

I am trying to solve a typical transportation problem using optimization (minimize transportation costs), in GLPK or R.

A simple case: 4 producers situated in 2 provinces (A and B) are delivering a product to two exporters situated somewhere else. I have a cost matrix for each route producer-exporter (see below). The solution would be trivial, it is a typical example of the transportation problem.

Example:

```
production (id, province, tons)
            1  A      300
            2  A      800
            3  B      800
            4  B     1200

    export (id, sourcing_province, tons)
            5  A      400
            5  B      600
            6        2000

    routes (id_orig, id_dest, cost) 
               1  5  5.1
               1  6  3.2
               2  5  6.7
               2  6  7.2
               3  5  2.8
               3  6  4.1
               4  5  6.9
               4  6  5.3
```

However there are extra restrictions making the problem more complex: I know that the exporter (5) is actually sourcing a certain fixed amount from each province. In particular in the example above the exporter (5) has to source 400 Tn from province A and 600 Tn from province B. Exporter (6) has no restriction, he could source the goods from whichever province. I don´t find a way to express these restrictions.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider your problem in terms of edges. If 1, 2, 3, 4 are the producers and 5,6 the exporters, let say e15 is the flow from producer 1 to exporter 5, e25 from producer 2 to exporter 5 and so on.

With this notation, the problem becomes:

```
/* Objective function */
min: 5.1 e15 + 3.2 e16 + 6.7 e25 + 7.2 e26 + 2.8 e35 + 4.1 e36 + 6.9 e45 + 5.3 e46;

/* production limits */
e15 + e16 <= 300;
e25 + e26 <= 800;
e35 + e36 <= 800;
e45 + e46 <= 1200;

/* demand */
e15 + e25 + e35 + e45 >= 1000;
e16 + e26 + e36 + e46 >= 2000;

/* exporter 5 restrictions   */
e15 + e25 >= 400;
e35 + e45 >= 600;
```

The last two inequalities are the fixed amount constraints.

You can use [LpSolve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) for this problem. There is also an R package `lpsolveAPI` for this. The problem formulation above is already in LP-Format.

Comment: What if the amount of restrictions is too large for writing them manually? I was giving just an example, but the real case includes thousands of producers, hundreds of exporters and few hundreds of restrictions. Can I  call all those restrictions in a simple way using a matrix of restrictions?

Comment: Sure! The limits for lpsolve are the computation time and the memory of your computer. See the lpsolveAPI package for programmatically setting up the tableau.